# want to send drawable image from second activity to first and set that image to imageview in first activity only

Tags: android

Here's the Code to pass and get image through intent,

### secondActivity

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, PostVideoTagLocation.class);
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.index);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                Intent intent2 = new Intent();
                intent2.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
                startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent2);
```

### firstActivity

```
          if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add_photo);
                image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
              }
           }
```

Comment: Alright, so whats the question? what errors do you get?

Comment: See my answer below. My code works 100% (I tested it). If it helps you, please accept as the chosen answer

Comment: @Mujammil Ahamed- I am not getting the error,but image is not displayed on the image view. when i put code on oncreate it displaying but when i am using onActvityResult() then unable to show image

Comment: is it really necessary for you to send the drawable file? you could send its id/name/url

Answer (score 0):

Inside PostVideoTagLocation's onCreate method you can simply create a bitmap from the byte array that the creating activity has passed.

[getIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()) method results in the intent that was used to create this activity, which will contain a bundle containing the picture bytearray.

However I am not completely sure how safe is it to store possibly big images inside an Bundle passed with Intent, so I would use this with caution.

You can use Intents [getByteArrayExtra()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getByteArrayExtra(java.lang.String)) with parameter "picture" which is used when you're setting the extra, and then simply with BitmapFactorys [decodeByteArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int)) decode it to an Bitmap.

Your code might looklike somethign like this

```
onCreate(Bundle bundle)..
   byte[] rawBitmap = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("picture");
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawBitmap)
```

and do with the bitmap whatever you want.

However I myself would save the image to a temporarily file and pass it with intent, just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

On your **first** `Activiy` you should call the **second** `Activiy` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PostVideoTagLocation.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1111);
```

Then on **Second** `Activity` when you want to send image to **first** `Activiy` you should call:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.index);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);

                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
```

Finally in the **first** `Activity` write this code on `onActivityResult`:

```
if(requestCode == 1111){
         Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
         byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
         Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
         mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
```

It should work (I tested it). Hope it helps you!

**[EDIT]** You can save your bitmap to a File and just put the File path to the `Intent`